# How to scatter chunks of data on cluster nodes without running out of memory

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, chunks, mpi4py, pbs

I wrote a code in Python which implements `mpi4py` to scatter chunks of data across the processors of a cluster. Each processor writes the given chunk of data into a `.txt` file, then all these `.txt` files are merged in one.
Everything is working as expected.
However, for very large `.txt` files, the cluster is complaining about memory:

```
mpiexec noticed that process ... rank ... on node ... exited on signal 9 (Killed)
```

I'm trying to set the parameters in the PBS file in a way which avoids this issue. So far, this is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash

## job name and output file
#PBS -N test
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o job.o
#PBS -V

###########################################################

# USER PARAMETERS

##PBS -l select=16:mpiprocs=1:mem=8000mb

#PBS -l select=4:ncpus=16:mem=4gb
#PBS -l walltime=03:00:00

###########################################################

ulimit -Hn

# number of processes
NPROC=64
echo $NPROC

CURRDIR=$PBS_O_WORKDIR
echo $CURRDIR
cd $CURRDIR

module load anaconda/2019.10
source activate py3

cat $PBS_NODEFILE

echo starting run in current directory $CURRDIR
echo " "
mpiexec -n $NPROC -hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE python $CURRDIR/test.py
echo "finished successfully"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

MPI uses distributed memory, that is, if you have more data than fits in one process, you spread it over multiple processes, for instance on multiple computers. So "scattering" data often doesn't make sense: it assumes that all this too-much data actually fits on one process. For a true MPI program, your processes all create their own data, or read it from a file, but you never have all data in one place.

So if you're dealing with lots of data, then a scattering approach will of course run out of memory, but it's the wrong way to approach your problem to begin with. Rewrite your program and make it truly distributed memory parallel.